# How to properly handle multiple model associations to different keys in Rails 4.0.8

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, data-modeling, model-associations

I'm having the following problem while trying to model my application, it's basically a functionality to handle bills with multiple people, like sharing the rent or any other similar stuff, the deal is:

I have a user model and a billing model but can't find out how to build the associations.

A **user has_many billings** and **billings belongs_to user** but, also the **billing has_many users**, e.g. Tom registers a bill that is meant to be shared by Tom himself, Betty and Bob.
So that makes Tom the creditor and the other two become debtors in the billing.

I'm kinda lost at this point, how to consolidate these associations, dunno if any more information is needed or if it's clear enough, but will appreciate any help and update with any other information needed.

Thanks in advance,

---EDIT---

I've come to the following approach:

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :billings, foreign_key: "creditor_id", dependent: :destroy
end

Class Billing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :creditor, class_name: "User"
  has_many :debts, dependent: :destroy
end

Class Debt < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :billing
  has_one :user
end
```

I also tried to graphically model it for better understanding here: [imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3deA.jpg)

Would that all be correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't be afraid to use the options available to you in `ActiveRecord`. If your model naming is getting cluttered (Billing belongs to a User and has_many Users) then be more specific with the association labels and sort the links with options. The [Rails Associations Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) is easy to Google and covers pretty much everything.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :billings, :foreign_key => 'creditor_id'
  has_many :debts, :through => :debtor_users, :source => :billing
end

class Billing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :creditor, :class_name => 'User'
  has_many :debtors, :through => :debtor_users, :source => :user
end

class DebtorUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :billing
  belongs_to :user
end
```

You can extend the `Billing` model to have multiple creditors also simply by converting the `belongs_to` association into a `has_many :through` association following the same pattern as debtors just with a different join model (say `CreditorUser`).

Comment: I've researched a bit more and studied your answer and think I'm getting the hang of it, thank you.
I also added some more information I've collected to the question.